# GRASS GIS data display

Tags: grass-gis

I have to import data vector and raster into GRASS GIS database. I try several projections and I don't know why I can't display the data in **Grass GIS**. But I can display my data with the grass plugin in QGIS...

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a link to the data (or a subset) so I can try it? Are there any error messages?

Comment: Thanks Rob for your help! Here's the link for the data! https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ko7l8s5ql2ji11u/AAB8Yh6tv6MmO684luueAJ0wa?dl=0

Comment: And no there's no error messages...

Comment: I have no problem loading and displaying both datasets in GRASS 7.1 (using EPSG:4326.) Is the region correctly set to the extent of your data? You can force this when you import by checking "Extend region extents based on new dataset" in the import dialog.

Comment: Hi Rob, i try using espg 4326 and still cannot display my data. I try " extend region extens based on new dataset" still notting. Im working with grass giss 6.4.3 but technically it should work....??

Comment: When i do " ste computional region for selected map" here's the error message: (Tue Aug 04 00:23:00 2015) Command finished (0 sec)                             
Command 'd.vect map=bdtq_batim_p_point@georges4326' failed
Command 'd.rast -o map=w001001@georges4326' failed

Comment: I just install Grass Gis 7 and it work ??? what the hell!! well thanks for your help!!

Comment: Hah! Sometimes that's all it takes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in your comment, the upgrade to GRASS GIS 7 helped - a lot has been invested to simplify the usage (more to come!). Be sure to consider for raster data the [computational region](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region), however, this is easily done via right mouse button in the map layer manager.

Note that you can create a GRASS GIS location directly from the data set: http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_Location_Wizard
This will be further simplified in the next version.